# Alloy: facts etc. about Int

Tags: integer, alloy

i am recently working with Alloy. 
Can I say something like:

```
fact{
all i: Int | i >= 0 
}
```

I want to say: all Integer which Alloy uses should be positive. 
Alloy doesn't fail but also don't give me instances.

greetings

Comment: I had a similar question, the answer may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690845/alloy-define-relation-to-only-positive-integers/52697248?noredirect=1#comment92330595_52697248

Answer (score 2):

You can't currently say that.  The only scope you can specify for integers (which tells Alloy which integers to "use") is the bitwidth (e.g., `4 Int`); Alloy then always uses all integers within that bitwidth (e.g., for bitwidth of 4, integers used are `-8, ..., 7`).

If you have a field of type Int in your model, you can use a fact (like you said above) to restrict its values:

```
sig S { i: Int }
fact  { all s: S | s.i >= 0 }
```

Comment: but i have a little issue with that:
I want to say: that an int is between 0 and somewhat.
for example i have this sig:
sig A{
id: int
}
and i use this facts:
fact{
all a:A | a.id > 0
}
fact{
all a:A | a.id < 20
}
I get no instances. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I realized that one fact is wrong. in the following my model and the fact I think is wrong:
` sig State extends StateOrJunction{
actionID:one Int, 
superState:lone State, 
subStates:set State}

 sig Transition{
conditionID:one Int, 
destination:one StateOrJunction, 
source:lone StateOrJunction}

abstract  sig StateOrJunction{
transitions:set Transition}`

The fact I suppose is wrong is the following:
fact{
all s:State | no s':(State-s) | s.actionID = s'.actionID
}
I want to say that all states have disjoint actionIDs.